# why can't substitute with sed command?

Tags: sed

I want to substitute all the string   `define('DB_NAME', 'name_here');` with `define('DB_NAME', 'myname');`  in the file `wp-config.php`.

```
x="define('DB_NAME', 'name_here');"
y="define('DB_NAME', 'myname');"
sed  -i 's/$x/$y/g'   wp-config.php
```

There is no error message in the console,but nothing happen.
How can i  substitute all the string   `define('DB_NAME', 'name_here');` with `define('DB_NAME', 'myname');`  in the file `wp-config.php`?

Answer (score 2):

Its the single quote that makes the problem and make `sed` does not evaluate your variable.  Use double quote around the `sed` code instead.

```
x="define('DB_NAME', 'name_here');"
y="define('DB_NAME', 'myname');"
sed  -i "s/$x/$y/g"   wp-config.php
```

PS to see what is going on, wait with `-i` to you see output is correct.

```
sed  "s/$x/$y/g" wp-config.php
define('DB_NAME', 'myname');
```

Comment: `sed -i.bak` is middle ground, isn't it?

Comment: @gboffi yes then you have to a copy of the file if some goes wrong :)